# Libgdx game performance, batery intelligent mode vs best performance mode

Tags: android, performance, mobile, libgdx, battery

I've made game for android (using libgdx). Today I've noticed that its performance drastically drops down when I change battery saving mode from best performance to intelligent.

I've noticed this before in other games but only when I've changed mode from intelligent to saving battery mode (or when it was very low).

Question is, is there a Flag/Manifest or something like that in native Android and/or libgdx that says to system; "Hey, give me more energy! I have to work better"?

Phone I tested it on was Honor 7.